# Synonym proposal [apache-sqoop] -> [sqoop]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Both refer to the same project however [sqoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqoop) has 2079 questions to [apache-sqoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-sqoop) which has 279.  This is similar to [zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zookeeper) and [apache-zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-zookeeper).

Comment: Shouldn't it have the `apache` prefix instead like apache-zookeeper?

Comment: @jontro I imagine that sqoop is far less likely to end up meaning something else as well compared to zookeeper